# Proof of $\cos(y)$ and $\sin(y)$ using $e^{iy}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I need to use that $e^{iy} = \cos y + i \sin y$ (for $y \in \mathbb{R}$) to prove that $$\cos y = \frac{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}}{2}$$  and $$\sin y = \frac{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{2i}$$
I'm really clueless, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know anything about the even/odd aspects of sin and cos?  Like what cos(-x) and sin(-x) are in terms of cos(X) and sin(x)?

Comment: A simple case of substitution followed by simplification will achieve what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$e^{yi} = \cos y + i \sin y$$
$$e^{-yi} = \cos y - i \sin y$$

Solve...

Comment: Thank you, I clearly hadn't put enough effort into my research.

Comment: @fadaes no problem. Don't worry

Answer (score 2):

You face a single equation in two unknowns, let $c$ and $s$,
$$c+is=e^{iy}=z.$$
Without knowing the parity trick, you need a second relation to make a determined system. Let us try with
$$c^2+s^2=1.$$

**Method 1**

We can factor
$$c^2+s^2=(c+is)(c-is)=1,$$
so that 
$$c-is=\frac1{c+is}=\frac1z,$$
and, solving a linear system,
$$c=\frac{z+\frac1z}2,s=\frac{z-\frac1z}{2i}.$$

**Method 2**

Let us make $s$ explicit from the first equation and plug it into the second
$$s=\frac{z-c}i=-i(z-c),$$
$$c^2+s^2=c^2-(z-c)^2=2zc-z^2=1,$$
giving
$$c=\frac{1+z^2}{2z},$$
and 
$$s=\frac1i\left(z-\frac{1+z^2}{2z}\right)=\frac{z^2-1}{2iz}.$$